# cmake FetchContent not downloading with DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT in docker

Tags: docker, cmake, fetchcontent

My `CMakeLists.txt` downloads a JAR file with `FetchContent`, which works as expected in Ubuntu 18.04 WSL. Running cmake in docker, does however not download the file.

I specify `DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT TRUE`, since it otherwise extracts the JAR file. Without it, it does extract the JAR contents in docker.

Here's a minimal reproduce.

`CMakeLists.txt:`

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.7 FATAL_ERROR)

include (FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  AntlrJar
  URL      https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar
  SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dependencies
  DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT TRUE
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(AntlrJar)
FetchContent_Populate(AntlrJar)
```

`Dockerfile:`

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /src

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y cmake g++

COPY CMakeLists.txt /src
```

And then I just execute `cmake .` in `/src` and notice "dependencies" being empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter `SOURCE_DIR` of `FetchContent_Declare` (and of `ExternalProject_Add`) affects where the downloaded file will be **unpacked**:

> `SOURCE_DIR <dir>`
>
> Source directory into which downloaded contents will be unpacked, or for non-URL download methods, the directory in which the repository should be checked out, cloned, etc.

(cited from [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)).

For specify directory where **downloaded** file will be **stored**, use `DOWNLOAD_DIR` parameter:

> `DOWNLOAD_DIR <dir>`
>
> Directory in which to store downloaded files before unpacking them. This directory is only used by the URL download method, all other download methods use SOURCE_DIR directly instead.

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  AntlrJar
  URL      https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar
  DOWNLOAD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dependencies
  DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT TRUE
)
```